# ColdFusion http request calling NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, coldfusion

I am having an odd issue using ColdFusion cfhttp to call a NodeJS application. It returns status `200 OK`, but it never calls the NodeJS functions.

NodeJS app.js

```
const mainRoute= require('./routes/mainRoute');

app.use('/mainRoute', mainRoute);
```

The mainRoute.js

```
const myController = require('../../controllers/myController');

router.get('/abc/test', myController.getReport);
```

Controller:

```
exports.getReport = async (req, res, next) => {
   console.log('here');
}
```

When I run it using the browser, it works just fine and show the log ```here``

I tried to run it in my ColdFusion application:

```
<cfhttp result="reportURL" method="GET" charset="utf-8" url="http://localhost:3006/mainRoute/abc/test">
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#reportURL#" />
```

It returns never shows the log `here` in the NodeJS running application and the output in coldfusion dump is the image below

[image]

Comment: From the ColdFusion dump it seems like the request was handled correctly. It received a 200 OK response. Are you sure you are looking in the correct place for the `console.log()` output?

Comment: Yes, I am. It's very odd

Comment: The `cfhttp` 'browser' is just executing an HTTP GET request, it retrieves the resource but it is not executing any javascript that might happen to be returned, so it won't be running that console.log command.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. Look in the NodeJs console. So, when you start your node server, it will open up a terminal window. Look in here for console messages.